# jQuery + HTML code does not work on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Last time I post about this damn code (Probably not, haha!) but I have the code working perfectly fine on Desktop and Tablet, however once it goes to mobile, the code breaks and I get a bunch of NaN errors. Have I used any depreciated code that is not support on mobile?

Tested on Pixel 3 XL + Chrome Dev Tools (Responsive Mode).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="title">VET Student Loans Repayment Calculator</p>

<p class="text">
  <br><br>   How much do you earn per year?
    </p>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select onchange="calculateTotals()" name="annualincome" class="input" id="income" placeholder="Your Annual Income">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Your Annual Income</option>
      <option value="0">Below $45,881</option>
      <option value="0.01">$45,881 - $52,973 (1%)</option>
      <option value="0.02">$52,974 - $56,151 (2%)</option>
      <option value="0.025">$56,152 – $59,521 (2.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.03">$59,522 - $ 63,092 (3%)</option>
      <option value="0.035">$63,093 - $66,877 (3.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.04">$66,878 - $70,890 (4%)</option>
      <option value="0.045">$70,891 - $75,144 (4.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.05">$75,145 - $79,652 (5%)</option>
      <option value="0.055">$79,653 - $84,432 (5.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.06">$84,433 - $89,498 (6%)</option>
      <option value="0.065">$89,499 - $94,868 (6.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.07">$94,869 - $100,560 (7%)</option>
      <option value="0.075">$100,561 - $106,593 (7.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.08">$106,594 - $112,989 (8%)</option>
      <option value="0.085">$112,990 - $119,769 (8.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.09">$119,770 - $126,955 (9%)</option>
      <option value="0.095">$126,956 - $134,572 (9.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.10">$134,573 and above (10%)</option>
    </select>
<p class="text">
Course Cost
    </p>
  <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="input value1" placeholder="0">
    <p class="text">20% Loading Fee</p>
    <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" id="loading" disabled="disabled" placeholder="0"><br>
    <p class="text">Total VET Student Loan Amount</p>
    <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" disabled="disabled" id="result" placeholder="0"><br>
  <p class="text">
    Your estimated after tax repayments are; <br><br> Per Year
    </p>
    <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" disabled="disabled" id="peryearresult" placeholder="After Tax Repayment - Yearly">
    <p class="text">
    Per Month
    </p>
    <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" disabled="disabled" id="permonthresult" placeholder="After Tax Repayment - Monthly">
        <p class="text">
    Per Fortnight
    </p>
    <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" disabled="disabled" id="perfortnightresult" placeholder="After Tax Repayment - Fortnightly">
        <p class="text">
    Per Week
    </p>
    <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="number" class="input" disabled="disabled" id="perweekresult" placeholder="After Tax Repayment - Weekly">
```

JS + jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
                calculate();
            });

            $('#income').change(function() {
                calculate();
            });

            function calculate(){
                var val1 = parseFloat($('.value1').val());
                var val2 = parseFloat($('.value2').val());
                var val3 = parseFloat($('.value3').val());
                var val4 = parseFloat($('#income').val());
                var sum = val1 + (val1 / 100 * 20);
                $("input#result").val(sum);

                sum = (val1 / 100 * 20);
                $("input#loading").val(sum);

                sum = Math.round(((val1 + (val1 / 100 * 20)) * val4) * 100) / 100;
                $("input#peryearresult").val(sum);

                sum = Math.round(((val1 + (val1 / 100 * 20)) * val4 / 12) * 100) / 100;
                $("input#permonthresult").val(sum);

                sum = Math.round(((val1 + (val1 / 100 * 20)) * val4 / 26) * 100) / 100;
                $("input#perfortnightresult").val(sum);

                sum = Math.round(((val1 + (val1 / 100 * 20)) * val4 / 52) * 100) / 100;
                $("input#perweekresult").val(sum);

                }
        });
```

Comment: Has this got anything to do with your keyup event? Does the keyup event trigger on mobile devices when there is no keyboard? Perhaps some routine is being performed, but your calculate function hasn't been called.

Comment: Hmm good idea. I'll try a bit of research on that and see if thats the issue. I could try and change it to touchend or input and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Hmm, it didnt. Changing keyup to input or touchend breaks the code.

Comment: I think the best way is to combine them like :  .on('keyup input', function(){  ... Did you tried sthg like this?

Comment: Updated the code to .on('keyup input', function(){, but it still throws a bunch of NaN errors in the output fields on mobile. Works great on Desktop and Tablet.